# UIScrollView Height and width

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I am facing one strange problem, using the below code I am making the UIScrollView to full screen.

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;
CGRect scrollFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
self.imageHostScrollView.frame = scrollFrame;
NSLog(@"Scroll Height: %f, Width: %f",screenHeight,screenWidth);
```

The problem I am facing when the iPad is in the Portrait mode, the height will be big and width will be small, instead I am getting height smaller and width bigger (same happens in Landscape mode also).

Portrait mode the value I am getting is

Scroll Height: 768.000000, Width: 1024.000000

In Landscape mode the value I am getting is

Scroll Height: 1024.000000, Width 768.000000

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the way you're setting the `self.imageHostScrollView.frame` is silly. You are effectively hard-coding assumptions about the *screen* into the frame of a *view* — two things that are completely unrelated to one another.

Instead, use auto layout to pin the edges of the scroll view to the edges of the *window*. That way, whatever the window may do from now on — making no assumptions about what that may be — the scroll view will continue to fill it exactly.

Comment: Yes your solution helped me but I needed the above code for full screen (don't know the reason)... anyhow this achieved what I needed. thanks